# Use of jQuery on Eclipse

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, eclipse, jsp

I'm trying to use the jQuery JavaScript library on a .jsp file but Eclipse does not recognize .
The library is on Practica1->WebContent->js->jquery-1.11.3.min.js, and my .jsp file contains this.

```
<script src="/Practica1/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

I need to add the jQuery on JavaScript resources?

[image]

> I dont want to use google libraries or something else like this.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Try `<script src="/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Try dropping the first `/`? Btw, does it load the CSS and bootstrap? Note that you should include jquery BEFORE bootstrap.

Comment: where is your jsp relative to the js folder?

Comment: The jsp file is on WebContent folder

Comment: Are you using spring framework?

Answer (score 0):

Please try absolute path:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```